# Find missing but required files for running a script

Tags: matlab, deployment

While deploying packages of Matlab code using Matlab 2015 I encountered the problem of gathering all required files from my repository to run a certain file or set of files. Matlab has a method for simplifying this process, [matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html).

However, sometimes some files are missing in the repository (either because I got a package from someone else who was not that careful or because it was not checked in in the repository).

When running the code one would get of course an error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'XXX'.
```

However, this may take long to fix (running takes long, you would have to repeat for every missing file). Therefore I thought to use the function above. Unfortunately, it only lists existing files in the output (I tested this). Functions that are called from your code, but that are not present in the current path are omitted by `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`.

My problem: I would like to get a list of all files that are required by running a certain file but are not present in the current path so that I can find them and add them to my collection.

I know that this must be an iterative process because the missing files could themselves call other missing files and I know that there would be false positives, some of these items could be unknown variables instead, and I know that the missing files would only have a name, no path (of course).

My question: What is the easiest way to find a list of potentially missing files of my code in one go?

Please note that function `depfun` [has been removed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html) in recent versions of Matlab.

Comment: You can use the file exchange submission [`fdep`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep--a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder) and it will return a struct which contains a list of functions/variables that were not defined.

Comment: @Suever I already tried fdep with Matlab 2015. Matlab gave an error refusing to use function depfun and referring me to matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts.